# BASH - look for file in for loop issue

Tags: bash, for-loop, extension-methods

So the issue is the following:
I have a folder with 4 .zip's and .md5's for all of them with the same base filename.

I have a FOR loop:

```
for S in *.zip;
do  
    {
        check_md5
    }
done

check_md5 ()
{
    if md5sum -c ${S:0:-4}.md5;
    then
        unzip_file
    else
        echo "MD5 failed"
    fi
}
```

The problem: the script for the first zip runs fine, but when the unzip_file process ends it doesn't update the S variable to the next zip's filename.

During the unzip_file process it moves out of the original folder and at the end of it moves both the current 'S' .zip and .md5 to a archive folder.

Is it possible that the bug happens, because the unzip_file script moves out of the original folder or because it moves the first .zip and .md5 out of the original folder before it jumps to the next cycle?

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `unzip_file`? is it a script, or a function. What does it do?

Comment: `unzip_file ()
{
 unzip -o ${S} -d originaldir/unziphere/
        mv originaldir/${S:0:-4}.md5 originaldir/archive/
        mv originaldir/${S} originaldir/archive/
 cd originaldir/unziphere/
}`

Comment: @SDK Why does the `unzip_file` function `cd` at the end? That seems to be what's causing the problem, and it doesn't do anything useful inside the function... why not just remove it?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson the script does a lot more (svn commit, mail sending, etc), but I couldn't post the full content.

Comment: @SDK Using `cd` in scripts always makes me nervous. It's too easy to get confused about where you are at what point (as in this problem), and things can get even weirder if any `cd` command fails for any reason. I much prefer to use explicit paths (either literal paths, or variables that define which directory to work in like dirToWorkIn="originaldir/unziphere"; ls "$dirToWorkIn").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the end of the first iteration you end up in a different directory. Following is one possible fix.

```
CWD="$PWD"  # remember current working directory path
for S in *.zip; do
    check_md5
    cd "$CWD"  # come back to the initial working directory at the end of each iteration
done
```

Though not related to the question, I would prefer passing the file name to the function instead of accessing a variable set somewhere else. I find it hard to troubleshoot and more error prone.

```
unzip_file()
{
    echo "unzipping $1"
    # ...
}

check_md5()
{
    if md5sum -c "${1:0:-4}.md5"; then
        unzip_file "$1"  # pass the argument forward
    else
        echo "MD5 failed"
    fi
}

CWD="$PWD"  # remember current working directory path
for S in *.zip; do
    check_md5 "$S"  # pass file name as an argument
    cd "$CWD"  # come back to the initial working directory
done
```

As another note, your function naming/modularization doe not look good. e.g. `check_md5` does a lot more than just checking `md5` sum.

Comment: Thanks, I also suspected that the issue is with the working directory change. Also thanks for the fine tune ideas.